# Avoid spawning points when inside bounding box of object(s)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a plane that I am spawning points on. I also have a collection of objects that should be avoided when spawning points. I generally know I'll want to use the bounding box of the collection, but I don't know how to generate the booleans for "safe" areas vs. "unsafe" areas. I hope I'm explaining this okay. I'm creating grass, and I don't want it to intersect with the objects.

This is my current node setup:
[image: current node setup]
The collection in the upper-left contains the objects I want to avoid.

I'm sorry if this is a common question. I tried Googling, but I couldn't find anyone else actually asking the same question.

Comment: You could enlarge your objects by the safe distance of choice, then use them to cut away from the spawning plane (you might want to solidify this plane first for proper boolean, and then delete the new faces created in solidification), then use it to boolean cut from the spawning plane, now use the cut plane to distribute points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try it e.g. with geometry proximity, which has some disadvantages, e.g. you need "enough" faces so that it works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked great, thank you!!